# Generate cached metadata with scons

Tags: scons

I have build process where I have a set of input files I want to build slightly differently based on slow-to-extract meta-data I can find in the input files.

The simple approach would be to get this information from the file every time I run scons and build conditionally based on it but it means I need to rescan the files every time I start a build significantly slowing down the build.

I have two potential approaches I'm looking to explore:

1. A two stage build where I first run one scons file to extract the metadata into sidecar files. These sidecar files get picked up by a second scons project that generates the right build targets and operations based on the sidecar files.
2. (Ab)use a custom scanner for the input files to generate sidecar files with the metadata in and enable the implicit_cache to make sure scanning only happens when the input files changes.

What would be the most correct and scons-idiomatic way of accomplishing what I'm looking to do?

Comment: Giving this as a comment because it's probably not what you want to hear: the most correct and scons-idiomatic way would be to rescan every time, sacrificing some speed for build robustness and correctness. ;) BTW, how "significantly" is your build slowed down? Can you give us some actual numbers and timings?

Comment: With hot caches it goes from 30 seconds to a minute for an empty build when I rescan the metadata.

Comment: so basically now you're doing this: scan file to get info (takes a long time), depending on info calling different builders on the file?  Can you paste an example of your processing of meta data and it's impact on your scons logic? Or maybe just paste your whole thing so we can work from more complete info?

Comment: I can't give you any specific examples since I'm working with proprietary tools at this point. 
I can talk in general terms though: The type of metadata I'm looking to extract long term would be things requiring me to look at every single vertex of a multi million vertex 3d object saved in a compressed format and use the information found to decide what type of build process I need to apply to it.